# Checking maximum current provided by charger, how?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, current-measurement, multimeter

Using only an entry-level multimeter (and an assortment of common discrete PTH components, say on a breadboard), what could be a reliable way to check the **maximum current** that a switched-mode AC-DC adapter can supply ?

The adapter in question is a typical mobile phone AC-DC adapter that is rated for 5VDC @ 800mA output, with 220-240VAC input. However, this is an el-cheapo east-asian generic, so hopefully one understand my reasons, to check if this can really source 800mA @5VDC or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find the maximum current a power supply can provide, check its nameplate.  In your case it says 800 mA at 5 VDC.  There is your answer.

Unless you think the manufacturer was being deliberately fraudulent, (a legitimate concern for no-name supplies especially from the far east), then you have to do your own measurements.  However, you won't be able to determine the supply's maximum current. You can't verify that it meets its specs without a lot of fancy testing, only that it doesn't fail them.  Put another way, with simple tests you can't prove compliance, only prove or fail to prove non-compliance.

To check that the supply can do what it say *at one set of environmental conditions*, give it the maximum load it is supposed to be able to handle and check the voltage and ripple.  From Ohm's law, 5V / 800mA = 6.25Ω.  This is the resistance you should put accross the supply while verifying it keeps its voltage within spec.  Note that this will dissipate 4 W if the supply works correctly.  Make sure to size the resistor accordingly.

If you're not willing to go out and get a 6.25Ω 5W (always leave a little margin) resistor just for this purpose, you can build one up from a bunch of other resistors in various parallel and series combinations.  That helps spread out the power, so a few of the right 2 W resistors of common and standard values should get you close enough.

Once the supply is loaded at its maximum current, check both the average DC voltage and the AC component of the output.  This can be done with separate multimeter readings on the DC and AC settings.  The DC reading should be within spec.  If only the nominal voltage was given without a error tolerance, as is common on namplates, then figure anything more than 3% error is suspect for a regulated supply.  More than 100 mVpp ripple for a regulated supply is also suspect unless you have specific specs.  Note that 100 mVpp is a lot less when reported as averaged absolute value with a RMS fudge factor thrown in, as your multimeter probably does on its "AC" setting.  For example, a 100 mVpp sine wave would probably read as 35 mV "AC", and rather less when the ripple is sharp spikes instead of a sine.  A oscilloscope is the best way to really measure this, but with a AC voltmeter you can get some idea and also compare the value with small load and large load to see if there is significant increase.

Answer (score 2):

Get a low value resistor (like 6 ohms and high wattage like >4) and connect it in series with the supply and meter (make sure to be on the high current mode of the meter, so you don't damage it.)

However this really won't tell you much because even a crappy power supply will most likely be able to meet it's rating at least for a little while (before it overheats, etc.)

You may want to get a higher resistance resistor to start out with. Also if you cant find one, you can use several together to allow it to meet the resistor's resistance and power rating.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would use an active adjustable load to test over a reasonable amount of time, but for a basic test you could put it across e.g. a 6Ω 5W resistor (to limit current to ~0.83A) in series with your multimeter or current range. If you don't have a 5W resistor, then either parallel a few larger values or do the test very quickly, before any magic smoke has time to escape ;-)

Monitoring the output voltage is useful too, as you need to know whether the supply can hold it's output voltage at a high current. My bet is it will not reach anywhere near it's rating if it's anything like some of the cheapo switching supplies I've seen.

Comment: Thanks. I certainly do not have the resistors with such specifications handy. I have 0.5W (decent assortment), some 1.0W (but certainly 10Ω plus) and only very limited choice of 2W ones. So, can I do something like put 10 of the 100Ω (0.5W) in parallel for this test, but have to be done in say something like 10 seconds odd, to measure the current passing, via the DMM (in series) ?

Comment: Yes, you can put the 100&Omega; resistors in parallel - 10 will give you 10 Ohms and 5W, so this will test up to 500mA. You can run this continuously as the dissipation at 500mA will only be 5A * 0.5A  = 2.5W. If it handles this, you can keep adding more 10 Ohm resistors until you reach 800mA (16 10 Ohm in parallel will give you 6.25 Ohms, 5V / 6.25 Ohms = 800mA. To calculate parallel resistances use this formula: 1 / (1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3... + 1/Rn) They don't have to be the same value. For example, for 10, 20 and 30 Ohms: 1 / (1/10 + 1/20 + 1/30) = 5.45 Ohms.

Answer (score 2):

10 toggle switches and 10 50 ohm 1W resistors (i.e. 100ma each at 5V), and 2 banana sockets to plug the voltmeter into. You now have a convenient test fixture with 100 ma steps.

To find the max current, add in resistors until the voltage starts to sag, then back off one switch.

To test endurance, start with half its rated current (e.g 4 switches) for an hour. If it's still going and at a safe temperature ( 40C or less, or not too hot to hold) add a switch and repeat...

If you only ever have to test one of these, it's not worth doing. But if you have a bunch, it's worth spending an hour or so to make.